# Why is Symfony not working on shared host?

Tags: symfony, installation, shared-hosting

I installed Symfony on my local host and it is working like a charm.

But when I upload the project folder via php to my shared host it is not working.

I see only the message: `This site is currently under construction.`
I am using the right php version (7.1.)

This is my folder structure.

```
.DS_Store
.env
.env.dist
.git
.gitignore
assets
bin
composer.json
composer.lock
config
package.json
phpunit.xml.dist
public
src
symfony.lock
templates
tests
translations
var
vendor
webpack.config.js
```

Comment: That doesn't seems part of symfony, more like a pre-defined/default page of your shared host. Are you trying to access to the php page inside symfony's "public" folder?

Comment: @Federkun well, yes, there is the index.php

Comment: if I write `www.mydomain.com/public` I get the message `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`Warning: file_put_contents(/is/htdocs/wp123456_abc/www/project/var/cache/dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainerDeprecations.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: That's better, isn't? Just give the write permission of you /var/ folder, and enjoy.

Comment: @Federkun var is 750. What do you recomment? Recusively? But I need to see the page on `www.mydomain.com` without writing `public`

Comment: Your webserver need write access to that folder, and the files within it. Change permissions, or/and ownership of those folders/files if needed. Yeah, recusively. About your remove that "public", you need to point the webroot of your web server to the public folder, or just rewrite the url with what your hosting allow you to use.

Comment: @Federkun Ok, thank you, I think I understand now! Will check it out

Comment: Wooooow it worked!!!

Comment: @Federkun You are a genius! Made my day

Comment: No problem, have a good one.